# Errors after update php version

Tags: php

I get many error and the site not work after update the php version.

```
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094755 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094785 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094794 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094814 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094822 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094842 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094849 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094869 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094876 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
[Wed Sep 10 21:47:14.094902 2014] [:error] [pid 21347] [client 5.28.155.234:59471] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function session_register() in /home/**/inc/config.php on line 58
```

the code is:

line 81:

```
    {
        $text.=$e[$i]." ";
    }
```

config file line 58:

```
session_register("views");
```

Comment: Doesn't it say it right there "`Call to undefined function session_register() in /home/**/inc/config.php on line 58`"?

Answer (score 1):

There is all you need in your error messages:

```
variable: text in /home/**/inc/function.php on line 81
```

this means that the vairalbe `$text` isn't set before. So define the variable before.

The second is that `session_register()` isn't supported anymore. So replace it.

```
$_SESSION['views'] = 'test';
```

You had that errors before but you had disabled your Notices.

Comment: And how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this set inside an if?

```
{
    $text.=$e[$i]." ";
}
```

If it is, and the case will be false, then this variable will not be set at all. You can bypass this message by declaring it like `$text = '';` at the beginning of your script for example. This might not be the best practice, but it will get rid of the message.

Undefined offset refers to - what is really hard to determine without more code - that there is no such thing as `$e[3]`. Is it in a for loop? If so, it might be the issue, that you are using `$i <= something` instead of `$i < something`

Also, session_register is used only < PHP 5.4.0.

You can do this for example

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Comment: Have any solution to add code in the top and all work like in php 5.3?

Comment: Is it possible to post your php file as whole?

Comment: Looking at this, you either have to downgrade, or rewrite all of your files to be compatible with the newer version, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Before using `$text.=$e[$i]." ";` you have to define the `$text`. For example like `$text ="";` or `$text =[];` etc.